# Set all sheets' fill color to "No Fill" using VBA in excel

Tags: excel, vba, colors, background-color

How can I Set all sheets fill color to `No fill` using VBA in excel (all cells). Same as select all sheets, Select all cells (Control+A) and change `fill color` to `No fill`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Untested but should do the job:

```
Sub No_Fill_Wb()

Dim ws as worksheet

For each ws in Thisworkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Equivalent would also be ```ws.Cells.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone```

Answer (score 23):

I used "0" in my code (see below) working with Excel 2016 and it turned my columns black.

```
Master.Columns(Col_Start).Interior.Color = 0
```

Using "xlNone" per below, however, did work for me.

```
Master.Columns(Col_Start).Interior.Color = xlNone
```

Comment: This is because when you set `Range.Interior.Color`, it expects a long corresponding to the RGB values.  0 -> #000000 which is black.  `Range.Interior.ColorIndex` increments through the default color palette, for which 0 is No Fill

Answer (score -1):

xlNone doesn't work for BackgroundPatternColor but wdColorAutomatic does

currentCell.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic

Comment: There is no `Word` tag in question, `Excel` only.

Answer (score -3):

Hey guys you can use this for selecting "No Fill" option "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Interior.Color = xlNone" otherwise if you want to set any background color you can use this way "ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Interior.Color = vbgreen"